How to log/receive which class tries to inject my bean
In a Micronaut application:
For debugging purpose I want to find out which other bean(B) is injecting my current class(A) which is a singleton.
Lets assume i want to log the name of class(B) inside the @PostConstruct method.
So that it answeres the question: Which Class(B) caused the initialization of the bean(A)
How?

Option1 - BeanIntrospection
Register a BeanIntrospection. And in the PostConstruct of your bean get the calling details from beanIntrospection.getDefinition().
e.g
@Singleton
public class Person {
    private final BeanIntrospection introspection;

    public Person(BeanIntrospection introspection) {
        this.introspection = introspection;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        BeanDefinition<?> beanDefinition = introspection.getDefinition(this.getClass());
        String injectingBeanName = beanDefinition.getName();
        System.out.println("Bean injecting Person: " + injectingBeanName);
    }
}

Register BeanIntrospection in your application
@Factory
public class BeanFactory {
    @Bean
    public BeanIntrospection beanIntrospection(BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) {
        return new BeanIntrospection(registry);
    }
}

Option 2 - @Introspected + BeanContext
Alternatively, you can also leverage @Introspected
and in the postconstruct of Person class you can Iterate through beans to find the one injecting this class
@Introspected 
@Requires(beans = BeanContext.class)
public class Person {
...
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        beanContext.getBeanDefinitions().stream()
            .filter(beanDefinition -> beanDefinition.getBeanType().isAssignableFrom(Person.class))
            .forEach(beanDefinition -> {
                System.out.println("Bean injecting Person: " + beanDefinition.getBeanType().getName());
            });
    }
...
}

References: https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/ 
section 3.16 Bean Introspection 
https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/#introspection

Does option 2 work if Person is a singleton?

We have to add a scope for the injected bean. I forgot to add @Singleton in the pasted code above. But this works with @Singleton.
